# Reusable component React js with java

Tags: java, spring, jsp, reactjs

I'm new in react js. I'm trying to improve my current application which is based on Spring. I want to use react js to make reusable components. In my JSPs I've such kind of code.

```
<spring:message code="label.firstname" var="firstname"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="${firstname}" data-v-notempty="true" maxlength="15">
```

As this code resolves the message from messagesource. How to handle this type of code as a part of reusable component?

Comment: I do not know much about spring but this repo may help you https://github.com/winterbe/spring-react-example

Comment: @JosephFurlott I've already seen this example. They use nashron javascript engine to render react js at server side. While I don't want to do that.

Comment: JSP and EL markup gets processed by the web server and transformed into HTML, so JavaScript tools like React will likely have no idea how the markup was generated and will not be able to interact with that process.

Comment: @willOEM I know this JSP is processed by JSP container. My question is here only, is there any to process react js under JSP container before it goes to client? Or any another way to deal with such scenario?

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your question?  Describe the functionality you are looking for.  It is not clear right now exactly what yu are looking for.

Comment: @willOEM Whatever code I've put in my question is present in my jsp currently. I want to refactor this code as a component so that I can use that component whenever firstname is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Render your react javascript on server side is preferable. You could use Java Nashorn or call nodejs from your container.

Or just use client JS and render it in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Check these out:

- [Building Isomorphic Webapps on the JVM with React.js and Spring Boot(February 16, 2015)](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/02/16/isomorphic-react-webapps-on-the-jvm/),
- [Integrating React.js into Existing jQuery Web Applications(August 24, 2015)](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/08/24/integrate-reactjs-into-jquery-webapps/)